# Why are the number of Internet Explorer Add-ons different depending on where the Options are viewed?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-addons, control-panel

Viewing the Add-ons from *within* Internet Explorer with either

`Tools -> Manage-Add-ons`

or

`Tools -> Internet Options -> Programs tab -> Manage add-ons`

are different from what is shown when opening

```
Control Panel -> Internet Options-> Programs tab -> Manage add-ons
```

Why are they different? There might also be different from within Internet Explorer.

Comment: Left to the list of add-ons, there's a drop-down menu where you can select "Currently loaded add-ons" or "All add-ons." Select the latter and see if they now match up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [answered and resolved by @Isxek](https://superuser.com/questions/595649/why-are-the-number-of-internet-explorer-add-ons-different-depending-on-where-the/596550#comment732577_595649). The drop down button has the option to show "All add-ons".